# Coding an inventory system, with polymorphic items and manageable item types

Tags: django, polymorphism

We currently have an inventory system for our employees. It contains
laptops, phones, but also ergonomic chairs, fridges or software
licenses ... So very different stuff that admins can create/read/
update/delete.

After doing a version completely based on admin interface, I gave up
cause it didn't provide enough flexibility. So I rolled-up a complete
custom version, but there is far too much code to my taste ... it's a
pain to maintain.

Some of the problems I have been facing include :

- allowing the admins to add **their own item types** through an
  interface, e.g. : laptop, TV, ... so basically like if they could create Django models themselves with a set of attributes through an interface. Also item types are hierarchical, e.g. TV
  and Laptop are subclasses of ElectronicItem, which in turn is a
  subclass of Item, ...
- polymorphism : when listing all the items, they should be aware
  of what type they are, this in order to search/filter the list with
  javascript and also generate urls to the item detailed view.
- updating some attributes through Ajax, e.g. laptops have
  licenses. On a laptop detail page, I have a javascript  "manager", to
  associate/detach licenses to that laptop.

So I was wondering if anybody had a suggestion on what to use ! I
especially wonder if one of the django CMSes apps could help me,
because that does sound like functionalities a CMS could provide ! I was even thinking of a NOSql database ... but those sound like complicated solutions.

It is actually not the first time I am facing this problem of polymorphism with Django, and I still haven't found a good solution. So I kind of hope, their is something that I have completely missed, and that somebody can show me the light !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... at the time of the writing, Django is just not good with that.

Schema-free databases such as mongodb are a good solution for this problem, and Django simply doesn't support those out of the box.

So I gave up Django, and rewrote the whole thing in `node.js` with a mongodb database.

Answer (score 3):

The [Satchmo project](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) is a django based e-commerce solution, which allows to manage different products and different options for a given products. Maybe you could find some inspiration in there.

Another great tool for inheritance and polymorphism management is the [Django model utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils) project, and the `InheritanceManager` it provides.

I'm using in in production, to manage different kind of products (shirts, jackets, etc.), and it's really helpful.

** Edit **

As requested, an example of a inheritance.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    client = models.ForeignKey('clients.Client')
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Shirt(Product):
    color = …

class Pants(Product):
    …

products = Product.objects.all().select_subclasses()
# products[0] can be a Shirt, and products[1] can be a Pants
```

Note that I had to tweak a few things to make the code work with `select_related`, because of [this issue](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/issues/7).

Comment: Hi, I've always been tempted to work with inheritance into production, but I never dared. Really are you comfortable with inheritance. Can you share some example (on model with inheritance and some query throug models: product that is a shirt or jacket. product with price > X and get type, ...). Thanks a lot!

Comment: django-model-utils looks really good, I didn't know about it ! It would solve the polymorphism problem, but I don't think it would solve the "adding your own models through an interface" problem. I will look into Satchmo.

Comment: @sebpiq You could use [dynamic model creation](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) to dynamicaly create `Product` subclasses from data coming form db. But it's starting to being a bit complex :)

Comment: yeeaah ... it does feel very hackish :) And I can't believe I am the first one to ever encounter this issue ... Actually I am now looking to a complete custom solution with something like pickled fields, and filters with regex, but I am not sure either whether that's a good !

Comment: @ThibaultJ, notice this question [DB design to store different products for each customer order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502687/db-design-to-store-different-products-for-each-customer-order)

Comment: so, in Satchmo that's basically how they do : https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/src/1f01f208c262/satchmo/apps/product/models.py#cl-1356  , i.e. name/value pairs stored in the database and associated to a product.