# DB design to store different products for each customer order

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm building a simple way to insert customer orders into the db.
We have several products, each one needs different properties.

I've started designing the following tables:

```
CUSTOMER -> Order (FK to CUSTOMER) -> OrderItem (FK to Order)
```

Now I'm thinking How could I link product-specific tables to **OrderItem**.
Suppose I've two products: **product1 (room_name, width, height, color) and product2 (number, width, height, type, optionals)**. I'd create two different tables and link them with the **OrderItem**, to get specific options, am I wrong? (of course there will be more than just two products)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have one `Product` table with a one-to-many relationship between `OrderItem` and `Product`.  Put a `FOREIGN KEY` in the `OrderItem` table that points to its associated `Product`.

A design like yours would mean you'd have to add a table every time there was a new product.  That would not do.  You want to add products by inserting new rows.

Comment: I assume the OP is addressing the concept that different sub-class of Product can have different properties [`We have several products, each one needs different properties.`].  What option(s) would *you* advocate for dealing with that situation while maintaining keys for referential integrity?

Comment: Yep, a Product table with a ProductId and all the common fields for any product. Then you could have a look-up table to relate Product table with other specific tables such as Product1Detail or Product2Detail tables.

Comment: Have a ProductDetail table that points back to the Product.  It'd have to be 1:m with Product - name/value pairs for each field.

Comment: Agreed with @duffymo - if possible - avoid multiple product tables by extending any product-type specific fields through either metadata or multivalues (e.g. XML) or using the Entity Attribute Value pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options

1. IMHO I would choose an Inheritance pattern, i.e. a new table called "ProductBase" with a unique Surrogate. Product base would have a classification e.g. "ProductType" which would then allow you to join into the appropriate 'subclass' Product table. OrderItem would reference just the Surrogate. Referential Integrity is enforcable, and it gives the opportunity for extending to additional forms of products. It does however require the use of a common unique surrogate amongst all Product table types. If there are other tables (other than OrderItem) referencing Product, it would also avoid the use of having to FK to composite keys.
2. Nullable Foreign Keys in OrderItem, i.e. OrderItem would have nullable FK to both (all) types of Product Tables, although only one of them would be present on each row.
   By inner joining OrderItem to the appropriate Product tables would eliminate the 'wrong' product joins based on the NULLs. RI can still be enforced.
3. If you have the SAME type of Primary Key on all your Product subclass tables, then you could also add a single Product "Foreign" Key and a "ProductType" "Switch" on OrderItem. The problem here is that you can't enforce RI.

That said, I really wouldn't be creating a new table for each and every product - surely there are some broad 'categories' of Product which can be modelled in a uniform manner.

No doubt if you sell Aircraft and Groceries that you would probably need a *AircraftProduct* and a *GroceryProduct*, but surely *A300*, *Boeing 747* and *Cessna Skyhawk* would fit as rows inside *AircraftProduct*, even if there are a few 'optional' nullable fields in each table not applicable to all products in this 'category'?

**Edit** : First see Dems and Duffmo's posts to see if you can avoid the requirement for having multiple Product tables at all, by using EAV / Multivalue / Metadata patterns to model Product.

Comment: Option 3 *can* have referential integrity using composite keys and the base-table.  The Product base-table has a PK on (id,type_id) and the OrderItem table FKs using (product_id, type_id).  Then have multiple sub-class tables which also FK using (product_id, type_id)  [+1 for useful options]

Answer (score 1):

No approach can resolve all of the issues you may be dealing with, the choice you make depends on which factor is most important to you.

Most people shirk away from having multiple tables.  One reason is that you don't know how many tables you may end up with in the future.  Another is that your queries may also bloat by having to join to multiple tables.  And it may become a maintenance headache with multiple queries to update every time you add a table.  Finally, adding a table is not even remotely as friendly as adding a record (Do you really want your App to be able to create tables?).

One option is just to add more and more fields to the Product table.  By making the property fields NULLable, different products can use different fields.

But...  You may then need to add logic to ensure that ProductX -always- has a value in FieldA, but that ProductY always has a value in FieldB, etc.  And probably some meta-data about each product type so that your application knows which fields to use for which products.  You still may need to add new fields, which is possibly tidier than adding new tables, but you still probably don't want the Application doing.

An option that totally avoids using DDL to add a product is to further normalise your data, and have the product-specific-properties in an Entity-Attribute-Value table.  This is *initially* very attractive to many people as it is so generic and flexible.

- Product(id, name, another-global-property, etc)
- Product_Properties(product_id, property_id, property_value)

You'll probably have some meta-data and extra logic to ensure all the correct properties are used.  But now you just add records to a generic structure whenever you create a new product.

But what type should "property value" be?  It may need to hold strings, dates, numbers, anything.  You could make it a string and use the meta-data to know how to CAST the value.  Of you may have several value fields, one of each type, and a "field_type_id" or something to indicate which value-field should be read from.

It's also less friendly for certain searches.  If you know a product_id, finding the properties is easy.  If you want all products where the expiry date is in the past, you need to be careful about how you structure the data and indexes to make the query efficient.  But if you want (expiry < today AND cost > 50) then you get a much different query from what you are used to - Each value is in a different ROW instead of a different FIELD.

Search performance really does begin to shrink as query complexity increases and design considerations become more technical.

Which way you go depends on application functional requirement, architecture and design decisions, and a good helpful dash of 'taste'.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged question as django. Then you should read this recent post:

[Coding an inventory system, with polymorphic items and manageable item types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501822/coding-an-inventory-system-with-polymorphic-items-and-manageable-item-types)

In this post @ThibaultJ explain how to accomplish this with  [Django model utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils).

The idea is that you have a 'product' model and you inherit product1 and product2 from this model adding specific information for both. @ThibaultJ has posted intesting samples.

I will notice @ThibaultJ about this question. If @ThibaultJ writes an answer I will remove my post.