# Implementing multiple user types with Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

What is the recommended way to implement multiple user types using Django 1.5's new [configurable user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-beta-1/#configurable-user-model) functionality?

I would like to have two user types: private users and trade users, each with their own set of required fields.

There are two ways I can think to implement this:

### 1) Multi-table inheritance

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
  # ...


class PrivateUser(BaseUser):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  # ...


class TradeUser(BaseUser):
  company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  # ...
```

Are there any problems with using multi-table inheritance in conjunction with the configurable user model?

### 2) Using a single model with a "type" attribute

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
  user_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices={
    'P': 'Private',
    'T': 'Trade',
  })
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
  company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  # ...
```

This method would require some conditional validation dependent upon `user_type`.

Which of these methods best suits my use case? Or perhaps there is a better way of achieving this?

Also, In case number 1, how can I filter my users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Warning: Django 1.5 is very new and the people are still investigating its new features. So my answer is nothing more than my opinion, based on recent research to answer this question.

Both ways are valid ways to achieve the result, with its advantages and disadvantages.

Let's start with the:

**Second option**

- Without nested models and not modular. `AbstractBaseUser`, as the name says, is an abstract model and does not have a specific table
- Has unused fields
- You need to check the user_type for any iteration with the model that uses the extra fields:

  ```
  def foo():
      if user.user_type == 'Private':
          # ...
      else:
          # ...
  ```

The resulting SQL would be approximately as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "user_type" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "company_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**First option**

- Nested models with logical separation of entities
- Very lean
- You must implement `BaseUserManager` for each child **if you want to use** `create_user`-like functions
- You cannot access the subclasses with a simple `BaseUser.objects.all()`*

The resulting SQL would be approximately as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_baseuser" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE "myapp_privateuser" (
    "baseuser_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "myapp_baseuser" ("id"),
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "myapp_tradeuser" (
    "baseuser_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "myapp_baseuser" ("id"),
    "company_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

* Imagine the following situation:

```
>>> BaseUser.objects.create_user('baseuser@users.com', password='baseuser')
>>> PrivateUser.objects.create_user('privateuser@users.com', password='privateuser', first_name='His', last_name='Name')
>>> TradeUser.objects.create_user('tradeuser@users.com', password='tradeuser', company_name='Tech Inc.')
>>> BaseUser.objects.all()
[<BaseUser: baseuser@users.com>, <BaseUser: privateuser@users.com>, <BaseUser: tradeuser@users.com>]
>>> PrivateUser.objects.all()
[<PrivateUser: privateuser@users.com>]
>>> TradeUser.objects.all()
[<TradeUser: tradeuser@users.com>]
```

So, you cannot directly retrieve the subclasses instances by using `BaseUser.objects.all()`. There is an [excellent blog post](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) by Jeff explaining better how to accomplish "automatic downcast" from `BaseUser` to its childs.

That said, you should consider the advantages and disadvantages of each approach and their impact on your project. When the involved logic is small (as in the example described), both approaches are valid. But in a more complex scenario, an approach can be better than the other one. I would choose the multi model option because it is more extensible.

Comment: Excellent answer. The automatic down casting is exactly what I was missing. I'm going to go with option 1 and implement this. Many thanks.

Comment: [django-models-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils) can helps with inheritance. See @ThibaultJ answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502185/842935 ,  Automatic downcasting of models from querysets

Comment: Instead of `if user.user_type == 'Private':` you could define `@property` with the name `is_private_user` and use `if user.is_private_user:`. With nested models for the same purposes you should use `isinstance()` to check the type of user, but again, the same functionality could be achieved by implementing `@property`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should consider AbstractUser?

Answer (score 2):

The new custom user model you can assign only one model to AUTH_USER_MODEL. With multi-table inheritance you have two models. So that is a problem.

In the case of a single user model that covers both user types you could abstract the conditional logic in the model methods. You can also use different managers for different user types based on how much they are different. This could also help you in being explicit when working with a specific user type.

Other option could be to store only most common attributes in a single user model and then attach specifics of two user types into their own tables which are linked to your main user table.

If both users have most of the things in common (in terms of data at least), I would keep them in one place. In the end, I would think about what is simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my example above, `BaseUser` contains all of the fields necessary for authentication, so would be assigned to `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. I am all for keeping things as simple as possible, but am also trying to avoid denormalising the database.

Comment: If two user types have only 1 or 2 fields different, I don't see much advantage of normalization. But you are right, you can use BaseUser for AUTH_USER_MODEL. I was not aware of down casting, with that your first case makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a single model with a "type" attribute. Here is why:

- Only one table, only one model
- If you want to convert from one type to another you just change attribute
- Implement getters and setters for the fields that exists for one type and doesn't exists for other = much more simple to use.