# Trouble understaing User Object in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and creating a web app where a clients signs up to make a purchase and also a vendor can add his/her product for sale. After reading the documentation on django, I'm still not clear on the User in built Object provided by django. My question is:

1. Should i use the User in built object to satisfy my requirements. But after reading the documentation it seems the User object is mostly suited for admin privileges/superuser or am i wrong.
2. Since i will be having 2 Users, meaning having 2 different models in database. There will be 2 different views. The client or users only sees products for sale and vendor only sees his dashboard and products he/she wishes to put up for sale.

Coming from a Java perspective i could just create a Client class and a Vendor class but i want to do this in django and it seems from what i have read from the documentation they suggest to use the User object. Please how do i go about this or could someone give an example of how to go about this. Thanks much appreciated..

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16945358/1418794).

Comment: You don't necessarily need two different models. You should design your database wisely, and manage permissions properly. You can use `foreignkey` to link tables (models) and manage privileges. That ensures the integrity of data in your database. I suggest you have a look at database design principles (there are plenty or <1 hour videos on YouTube). Once you've done that, you'll be able to do this in a more elegant way.

Comment: @Xenatisch yes i have my database design setup the issue is modeling in django and coming from java i could write 2 classes but since django has a User built in class it's a little tricky

Comment: Have a look at this [Model creation, ForeignKey relations, testing and the Django Admin](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/model-creation-foreignkey-relationship-testing-django-admin), you might find it helpful.

Comment: Two separate models have a lot of benefits along the way. When pulling data, then it's much less error prone: you use Vendors.vendors_things_set.filter(...), and Client.clients_things_set.filter(...). This code will less likely generate an error where vendor gets client data, and vice versa, that can easily happen if you start with on model and forget to filter by client/vendor

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the java perspective is the database perspective, which is true for django as well:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   # ... more Client fields here

class Vendor(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   # ... more Vendor fields here
```

Note that these models allow a user to be a client and a vendor - or none at all. If a user can be only be a client **or** a vendor, or must be one of those classes, you will need additional validation. The User model will be used for the common features to all, such as authentication or other shared features (e.g. using the email to send a notification)

Comment: thanks for the response. I saw in the documentation they mentioned abstractbaseUser. will that be a good approach and will it make it scalable.

Comment: If you are new to django, I would recommend that you stick with the default User model. It touches so many parts of the framework.

Comment: will read the documentation again to get an understanding. It seems from previous reading earlier it's better to use the User Object and customized validations to suit your needs. Will really want to get this to work and understand it. Don't want to give up yet